# Why does this function get appended to my output when appending special characters

Tags: javascript

What is the proper way to "boldify" my text (convert normal characters) to corresponding special "Bold (serif)" symbols?

When I run it in my browser as `boldify("Hello World!")`, I expect:

> " !"

But I get (When ran inside google developer console in Opera):

> " !function(_0x3298c7,_0x4d4daa){return
>   this[_0x543a('0x9f')](new RegExp(_0x3298c7,'g'),_0x4d4daa);}"

What is this javascript function string that gets appended at the end? Why does that happen?

The function:

```js
function boldify(txt) {
  let input = txt;
  let bold_input = "";
  let font = {
    'q': [55349, 56362],
    'w': [55349, 56368],
    'e': [55349, 56350],
    'r': [55349, 56363],
    't': [55349, 56365],
    'z': [55349, 56371],
    'u': [55349, 56366],
    'i': [55349, 56354],
    'o': [55349, 56360],
    'p': [55349, 56361],
    'a': [55349, 56346],
    's': [55349, 56364],
    'd': [55349, 56349],
    'f': [55349, 56351],
    'g': [55349, 56352],
    'h': [55349, 56353],
    'j': [55349, 56355],
    'k': [55349, 56356],
    'l': [55349, 56357],
    'y': [55349, 56370],
    'x': [55349, 56369],
    'c': [55349, 56348],
    'v': [55349, 56367],
    'b': [55349, 56347],
    'n': [55349, 56359],
    'm': [55349, 56358],
    'Q': [55349, 56336],
    'W': [55349, 56342],
    'E': [55349, 56324],
    'R': [55349, 56337],
    'T': [55349, 56339],
    'Z': [55349, 56345],
    'U': [55349, 56340],
    'O': [55349, 56328],
    'P': [55349, 56334],
    'A': [55349, 56335],
    'S': [55349, 56338],
    'D': [55349, 56323],
    'F': [55349, 56325],
    'G': [55349, 56326],
    'H': [55349, 56327],
    'J': [55349, 56329],
    'K': [55349, 56330],
    'L': [55349, 56331],
    'Y': [55349, 56344],
    'X': [55349, 56343],
    'C': [55349, 56322],
    'V': [55349, 56341],
    'B': [55349, 56321],
    'N': [55349, 56333],
    'M': [55349, 56332],
    '1': [55349, 57295],
    '2': [55349, 57296],
    '3': [55349, 57297],
    '4': [55349, 57298],
    '5': [55349, 57299],
    '6': [55349, 57300],
    '7': [55349, 57301],
    '8': [55349, 57302],
    '9': [55349, 57303],
    '0': [55349, 57294]
  };
  for (i in input) {
    let char = input[i];
    let char_code = font[char];
    if (char_code !== undefined) {
      let bold_char = String.fromCharCode(char_code[0], char_code[1]);
      bold_input += bold_char;
    } else {
      bold_input += char;
    }
  }
  return (bold_input);
}

console.log(boldify("Hello World!"))
```

Comment: running your code as snippet, seems to work ok

Comment: In JavaScript String is **not** an array of characters.

Comment: works fine with the provided code - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pozKGoQ?editors=1010

Comment: @CalvinNunes I ran it in google developer console in Opera browser.

Comment: I just run it here on StackOverflow, clicking in "Run Code Snippet", on my Chrome Browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either don't use `for(i in input)` construct - the most direct replacement will be `for ... of`

```
for (const char of input) { ... }
```

... or check that it only processes characters, and not the other props of the string with...

```
for (i in input) if (input.hasOwnProperty(i)) { ... }
```

Otherwise it'll start collecting functions added to String prototype. The very first function - `formatUnicorn` in my case (Chrome) - is added to the output.

---

As a sidenote, the function can be greatly simplified. For example, the same number - 55349 - is used as the first character code for all the boldings; it's a waste of time and space adding it to each element of the 'mapping' array, as it can be inlined in `String.fromCharCode(...)` call.

But even an array is a bit of waste here: if you pay attention, you'll see that there are just three sequences - one for `a-z`, another for `A-Z`, and final for `0-9`. These values should be stored, but not the intermediate ones.

Finally, you can target only the characters you have a replacement for with a simple regex.

For example (just a concept):

```
function _getAdditionalCode(char) {
  const charCode = char.charCodeAt(0);
  return charCode + (
     charCode >= 97 ? 56346 - 97 : // 'a'..'z'
     charCode >= 65 ? 56320 - 65 : // 'A'..'Z'
                      57294 - 48   // '0'..'9'
  );
}

function boldify(txt) {
   return txt.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, 
     ch => String.fromCharCode(55349, _getAdditionalCode(ch)));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained by [PM 77-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927706/why-does-this-function-get-appended-to-my-output-when-appending-special-characte#comment102273088_57927706), a `string` is not an array of chars.

That being said, different javascript interpreters may display different outputs.

What you can do is splitting the `string` and iterate through it.

Instead of `for (i in input)`, you should do `for (i in input.split(''))`.

This will split the string into a true array of chars, which you can safely iterate through.

---

One note about your code, you can simplify it using the [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax.

```
for (let char of input.split('')) { ... }
```

The `for...of` returns the value of what you're iterating in, instead of the index.